# Searching for time complexity of my recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

So I have an assignment from my school, and I only wondered what time complexity my algorithm has (not needed for answer per se, only the algorithm need to run faster than *O*(n) worst case))

The question is: Given n (n ≥ 3) distinct elements, design a divide and conquer algorithm to compute the first three smallest elements. Your algorithm should return a triple (x, y, z) such that x < y < z < the rest n − 3 input elements, and run in linear time in the worst case.

And my solution is as follows:

```
Solution: Since “n” must be ≥ 3, the given array cannot have less than 3 
elements. 

If n == 3, simply compare the elements to each other (maximum of 3 
comparisons needed). 

Compare the first 2 elements to each other and assign the elements with a 
“smallest element” and “2nd smallest element”, we’ll call 
them “x” (smallest) and “y” (2nd smallest) from here on out. Compare “x” 
(smallest) to the 3rd element. 

If x > 3rd element, we know that the 3rd element is the smallest in this 
array, therefore: “y” becomes the new “z”, “x” becomes the new “y”, and the 
3rd element becomes the new “x”. You’re now left with the desired output. 
Return the triple (x<y<z). (2 comparisons used)

Else if x < 3rd, make the 3rd element be “z”. Compare y with 3rd element 
(now “z”). 

If y < z, do nothing, you already have a triple with the desired outcome 
(x<y<z).

If y > z, swap the elements. You now have a triple with the desired outcome 
(x<y<z).
```

Now that the first case (n == 3) has been handled, let’s handle what should happen when n > 3.

```
If n > 3, split the array recursively into parts of n/2 (if n is an uneven 
number, split the array into parts of n/2 + 1 & n/2).

Keep doing the 1st step until the split arrays have a size of ≥ 2.

Compare the elements in each sub-array to each other, and assign a lowest 
and 2nd lowest value to them. (“x” and “y”)

When merging the sub-array, compare the lowest element of one sub-array, to 
the other array’s lowest value. 

If a1(lowest) < a2(lowest), make a1(lowest) be “x”, a2(lowest) the new “y”, 
and a2(2nd lowest) the new “z”, then compare a1(2nd lowest) with the highest 
value in a1 at that moment (“z” in this case). 

If a1(2ndlowest) > “z”, do nothing. (“x”, “y” and “z” are already the three 
lowest values in the sub-array)

Else if a1(2ndlowest) < “z”, swap the elements and make a1(2ndlowest) the 
new “z”, then compare the new “z” with “y”

If “z” < “y”, swap the elements.

No more comparisons needed, as the “x” is the lowest element from a1, which 
means the 3 elements, “x”, “y” & “z” are now the lowest possible from this 
subsection of the array. 

Repeat from step 4 until reaching the highest layer of the call, and you now 
have a triple that satisfies the condition (x<y<z).
```

Sorry about the wall of text (and pseudocode). I've read about time complexity, and I understand the simple ones (like a statement has constant time, a for-loop has time depending on how long it is, etc.) but I have a hard time understanding the time complexity for my own algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "such that x" ?

Comment: Whoops! Such that x<y<z

Comment: You can build a min-heap in O(n) time, and getting the three smallest items from the heap is O(1). But I don't think building a min-heap is considered a divide-and-conquer algorithm.

Comment: Your algorithm looks like a combination of a merge-sort and a heap selection algorithm. Your x, y, z merge logic is very similar to what you'd use if you want to select the top (or bottom) `k` items from a list of `n` items. That algorithm is O(n log k), but since `k` is constant in this case, the algorithm would be considered linear.

Comment: Unless you know something more about the n input elements (eg. that they are sorted), this cannot be done faster than O(n). And in fact the question you quoted just demands linear time (which is O(n)).

Comment: So you say that my solution has (in the worst case) a time complexity of  O(n)?

Comment: All I know is that the input array (n) has distinct elements in it, nothing else.